# magento 2 not working after the command bin/magento setup:di:compile

Tags: magento, magento2

Command:

`bin/magento setup:di:compile`

I have tried to upgrade my module with:

`$ php bin/magento setup:upgrade`

The end result was:

> Please re-run Magento compile command

After doing this magento site is not working.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 3):

change your var/ and pub/ folders permissions.

Answer (score 1):

In the **root directory** of your Magento run the command:

```
$ find var generated vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type f -exec chmod g+w {} + && find var generated vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type d -exec chmod g+ws {} + && chown -R :www-data . && chmod u+x bin/magento
```

It should fix your permission issues

Comment: Thanks it worked. For some reason  it worked without the $ sign. ANd also for some reason my folders are not www-data but my username. I swapped it with my username and the command was executed succesfully. I am on Siteground gogeek shared hosting account BTW

Answer (score 0):

Try running `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`
Also make sure ownership and permission is set correctly.

Answer (score 0):

in Magento 2 we need to setup proper file/folder permission.
so please try following command:-

> sudo chmod -R 0777 var/* pub/static/* app/etc/*

if don't load complete content run following command   :-

> php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

Answer (score 0):

You should run your compilation and generation commands as the magento-base file-owner, this can be done using `sudo -u username command-to-be-executed`

In any case, you should now try to fix your permissions, if this is a dev-environment yue can simply `sudo chmod 777 . -R` or preferably `chown user:group . -R` in your magento folder.

Answer (score 0):

To Upgrade a module, Run following commands

Step1: Navigate to Route Folder (check 777 permission for var & pub)

Step2: Run Upgrade Cmd (php bin/magento setup:upgrade)

Step3: Run Compile Cmd (php bin/magento setup:di:compile)

Once Upgrade command has run then run static commands also else error will occurs as 404 for pub/static files

Step4: Run Static Content Cmd (php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
)

Step5: Change permission to var & pub as 777

Answer (score 0):

The actual sequence of run the Magento script is given below:

```
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush
rm -rf generated/code/*
rm -rf generated/metadata/*
rm -rf var/di/*
rm -rf pub/static/frontend/*
rm -rf pub/static/adminhtml/*
rm -rf pub/media/catalog/product/cache/*
rm -rf var/cache
rm -rf var/page_cache
rm -rf var/log
rm -rf var/view_preprocessed
rm -rf var/composer_home/cache/*
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
chmod -R 777 var pub generated app
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
chmod -R 777 var pub generated app
```

If you want to avoid unwanted circumstances, then you should follow the above script sequence.

Answer (score 0):

Run following commend

```
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
chmod -R 777 var pub generated
```